# Authentication unavailable when i load data_asset with MLTABLE in Azure ML SDK Python2

Tags: python, authentication, machine-learning, azureml-python-sdk

```
    credential = DeviceCodeCredential()
    ml_client = MLClient(credential, 
                         auth_subscription_id, 
                         auth_resource_group, 
                         auth_workspace_name
                        )

VERSION="1"
data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="TEST_MLTABLE", version=VERSION)

import mltable

tbl = mltable.load(f"azureml:/{data_asset.id}")
tbl.show(5)
```

I have authentication with devicecodecredential in Python SDK2 Azure ML Studio. In many scripts everything its ok - i save a parquet, load, dataset etc. But in this code i have a error

> DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
> Attempted credentials:
> EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
> Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.
> ManagedIdentityCredential: No token received.
> To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot

In line

```
tbl = mltable.load(f"azureml:/{data_asset.id}")
```

I dont understand why... Where is a token? How i can use token in DeviceCodeCredential?

PS.
When i try data.get from dataset with parquet - everything its ok...

```
VERSION="3"
data_asset2 = ml_client.data.get(name="TEST2", version=VERSION)
df = pd.read_parquet(data_asset2.path)
```

The same ml_client... The same notebook....

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the scenario, with `DeviceCodeCredential`
[image]
It executed successfully.

Please recheck your permissions, azure.ai.ml package version and check [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication.md) documentation for properly set-up your credentials.

As alternate way, you can use `DefaultAzureCredential` as credentials for your `ml_client`.

Below is a sample code snippet:

```py
import mltable
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
ml_client = MLClient(
DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)
data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="sample_data", version=VERSION)
# create a table
tbl = mltable.load(f"azureml:/{data_asset.id}")
# load into pandas
df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
df.head(5)
```

[image]